# compare two list of tuples for jinja2

Tags: python, list, jinja2, list-comprehension

So here's the deal. I have some log files which im using to create an email. Im using a jinja template which lists the contents of the log files. However I've decided to add some data metrics where I am showing the the change from the last days log. Ok

My data is kept as a csv file and i load them as list of tuples in the form of [ ('string',int,int), (...) ] What I know how to do is use a list comprehension to compare the 'string' index, and if theyre equal, check for the last int in the tuple. if that integer is greater, Im adding a small arrow showing increase, if lower, show a decreased arrow.

So far I have bits and pieces of what I want to do. For instance this is the piece of code that populates my table in the jinja template file

```
  {% for f,r,u in data %}
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">&#9650</span>{{f}}</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">{{r}}</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">{{u}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

I havent yet added the conditional to show a down arrow if the result of the comparison is less than.

I came up with a very bad function to test the comparison of the lists. Im not condifent in how well it works.

```
def change(l1, l2):
    inc = [x[0] for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x[0] == y[0] and x[2] > y[2] ]
    dec = [x[0] for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x[0] == y[0] and x[2] < y[2] ]
    yield inc, dec
```

What I'd like is  a way to compare these two lists for the third integer and dynamically add the span to the table illustrating either an increase or decrease. Thank you and I hope I asked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a little weird (why are you using `yield`?), but it's largely there; only, if I understand correctly, you really want to be adding a fourth field to the data, so that you can then do something like:

```
{% for f,r,u, inc_dec in four_tuples %}
<tr>
  <td class="tg-031e"><span style="color:blue;font-  weight:bold">&#9650</span>{{f}}</td>
  <td class="tg-031e">{{r}}</td>
  <td class="tg-031e">{{u}}</td>
  <td>
  {% if inc_dec == -1 %}
      <!-- show decrease image -->
  {% else if inc_dec == 1 %}
      <!-- show increase image -->
  {% endif %}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If `l1` and `l2` are `new_list` and `old_list`, respectively, then you should be able to do something like:

```
def diff_to_int(a, b):
    if a < b:
       return -1
    elif a == b:
       return 0
    else:
       return 1


def change(new_list, old_list):
     """
     :type new_list: list[(str, int, int)]
     :type old_list: list[(str, int, int)]
     :rtype list[int]
     """
     return [diff_to_int(new_tuple[2], old_tuple[2])
             for new_tuple, old_tuple
             in zip(new_list, old_list)]


inc_dec_list = change(new_data, old_data)
```

Then to make each of your 3-tuples a 4-tuple with an extra field showing whether or not its an increase, a decrease, or static, you can do:

```
four_tuples = [(a, b, c, inc_dec_static) 
               for (a, b, c), inc_dec_static
               in zip(new_data, inc_dec_list)]
```

Then pass that into your template.

Comment: I think maybe youre on the right track here however I dont understand a couple of things in your code, namely what you're passing to diff_to_int(). What are the new_tuple[2] and old_tuple[2] for? The new 4-tple list is a good idea, so its just a copy of the new_list with the added field of increase,decrease or not (1,0,-1). I think maybe the list comprehension needs reworking. Ill try some variations of it.

Comment: Also I'd like to mention that the two list may not necessarily be the same size or have the exact same content. Only is the two strings in the tuple match do we care to check the second int value for change.